# WPF How to bind GridView column width in code?

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview, binding

I need to bind width property of the GridView column that is created dynamically in code.

Since GridViewColumn object has no SetBinding method, how should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BindingOperations.SetBinding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx)

Comment: Finally something that might work, thanks. No longer need this, but will try someday.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a SetValue within the event handler responsible for changing the width state of the column and update that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
gvc.Header = "Value";
Binding b = new Binding();
b.XPath = "./Data/@Value";
gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = b;
GridView.Columns.Add(gvc);
```